# I can't identify which class have this errors (odoo)

Tags: python, orm, odoo, openerp-8

I'm developing an OpenERP module and it contains too many class and when i try to install it i go that errors and i can't find which class have this error what should i do (i  develop with eclipse IDE)

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Mostafa\PycharmProjects\odoo\odoo8\openerp\http.py", line 517, in _handle_exception
        return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
      File "C:\Users\Mostafa\PycharmProjects\odoo\odoo8\openerp\http.py", line 538, in dispatch
        result = self._call_function(**self.params)
      File "C:\Users\Mostafa\PycharmProjects\odoo\odoo8\openerp\http.py", line 294, in _call_function
        return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Mostafa\PycharmProjects\odoo\odoo8\openerp\service\model.py", line 113, in wrapper
        return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Mostafa\PycharmProjects\odoo\odoo8\openerp\http.py", line 291, in checked_call
        return self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
      File "C:\Users\Mostafa\PycharmProjects\odoo\odoo8\openerp\http.py", line 754, in __call__
        return self.method(*args, **kw)
      File "C:\Users\Mostafa\PycharmProjects\odoo\odoo8\openerp\http.py", line 387, in response_wrap
        response = f(*args, **kw)
      File "C:\Users\Mostafa\PycharmProjects\odoo\odoo8\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 953, in call_button
        action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
      File "C:\Users\Mostafa\PycharmProjects\odoo\odoo8\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 941, in _call_kw
        return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Mostafa\PycharmProjects\odoo\odoo8\openerp\api.py", line 237, in wrapper
        return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Mostafa\PycharmProjects\odoo\odoo8\openerp\addons\base\module\module.py", line 450, in button_immediate_install
        return self._button_immediate_function(cr, uid, ids, self.button_install, context=context)
      File "C:\Users\Mostafa\PycharmProjects\odoo\odoo8\openerp\api.py", line 237, in wrapper
        return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Mostafa\PycharmProjects\odoo\odoo8\openerp\addons\base\module\module.py", line 498, in _button_immediate_function
        registry = openerp.modules.registry.RegistryManager.new(cr.dbname, update_module=True)
      File "C:\Users\Mostafa\PycharmProjects\odoo\odoo8\openerp\modules\registry.py", line 341, in new
        openerp.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
      File "C:\Users\Mostafa\PycharmProjects\odoo\odoo8\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 358, in load_modules
        loaded_modules, update_module)
      File "C:\Users\Mostafa\PycharmProjects\odoo\odoo8\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 263, in load_marked_modules
        loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
      File "C:\Users\Mostafa\PycharmProjects\odoo\odoo8\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 158, in load_module_graph
        models = registry.load(cr, package)
      File "C:\Users\Mostafa\PycharmProjects\odoo\odoo8\openerp\modules\registry.py", line 148, in load
        model = cls._build_model(self, cr)
      File "C:\Users\Mostafa\PycharmProjects\odoo\odoo8\openerp\models.py", line 653, in _build_model
        '_inherits': dict(cls._inherits),
    ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 11; 2 is required
```

Comment: I think their is no error with core modules. Might be comes from the custom modules. checkout one by one new custom modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very hard (verging on impossible) to answer without seeing your actual code. The problem is clearly in `_inherits` definition in one of your models.

Most likely you mixed up [`_inherits`](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#openerp.models.Model._inherits) and [`_inherit`](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#openerp.models.Model._inherit). While the later one can be a either a list or a single string, `_inherits` has to be a dictionary.

It seems you might have erroneously defined `_inherits` as a list (instead of dict), because you really intended to use `_inherit`.

Answer (score 1):

'_inherits': dict(cls._inherits), you just check it out whether you did right way or not. i am also beginner in openErp.but i think you have problem with this line. and Mr.Ludwik is correct without knowing the codes how can be possible to tell the error.